# How do I dynamically show/hide a line in a classic email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, vf-email-template, rendering

I'm working on a functionality that sends an email to the user with a links to a list of documents. The following is the code from `.email` VF template that does it.

```
<!-- starting lines of email --> 

Please find the the link(s) below:<br/>
<c:EG_FetchFiles recordId="{!rec.Id}">
</c:EG_FetchFiles>

<!-- ending lines of email -->
```

The `c:EG_FetchFiles` provides the links to related Files. I want to render the *Please find the the link(s) below* line only if the `EG_FetchFiles` provides any links.

I have tried `apex:outputPanel` with `rendered` condition as `{!rec.Id}` but this always evaluates to true. Is there a way I can render the line only if the component returns any links?

Comment: Could you refactor the EG_FetchFiles component to accept the preamble message as an attribute and ensure it is rendered if there is a link, and not otherwise?

Comment: @PhilW yeah, I have that down as the last resort but I'm still trying/hoping to find a way inside the VF page even if its a hack.

Comment: I don't think you will achieve what you want, even as a hack, and will need to make the component deal with this. Honestly, it's the right thing to do (though using a label would be even better since it would allow localization).

Comment: Does the outer VF email template relatedTo object have a field that is the count of files in a field. If so, you could use an apex:outputText with a rendered= property. Otherwise, Phil's suggestion is the right one